# tikz being mishandled by manuscriptcentral

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm submitting a paper through manuscriptcentral.  The paper uses `tikz`.  Here is the code for one of those figures:

```
%in preamble
\tikzset{box/.style={draw, minimum width = 1.cm, minimum height = 1.cm, text width=1cm, text centered, fill=white},
slantedbox/.style={draw,trapezium,trapezium left angle=70,trapezium right angle=-70, fill=colora!5, label={[shift={(-5ex,-3.5ex)}]top right corner:#1}}
}

%in main text

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [box] (phiQQ) at (0,0) {$\phi_{QQ}$};
\node [box] (phiQA) at (3,0) {$\phi_{QA}$};
\node [box] (phiQ*A) at (6,0) {$\phi_{Q^*A}$};
\node [box] (phiAA) at (4.5,-1.75) {$\phi_{AA}$};
\node [box] (phi*QA) at (3,-5) {$\phi^*_{QA}$};
\node [box] (phi*Q*A) at (6,-5) {$\phi^*_{Q^*A}$};
\node [box] (phi*AA) at (4.5,-6.75) {$\phi^*_{AA}$};
\node [box] (phi**AA) at (4.5,-10) {$\phi^{**}_{AA}$};
\path [->] (phiQQ) edge node {}(phiQA);
\path [->] (phiQA) edge [out=0,in=90] node {} (phiAA);
\path [->] (phiQA) edge node {} (phiQ*A);
\path [->] (phiQA) edge [out=270,in=180] node {} (phiAA);
\path [->] (phiQ*A) edge [out=270,in=0] node {} (phiAA);

\path [->, left] (phiQA) edge node[pos=0.7] {$\beta \phi_{QA}$} (phi*QA);
\path [->,right] (phiQ*A) edge node[pos=0.7]  {$\beta \phi_{Q^*A}$} (phi*Q*A);
\path [->,right] (phiAA) edge node[pos=0.3] {$2\beta\phi_{AA}$} (phi*AA);

\path [->] (phi*QA) edge [out=0,in=90] node {} (phi*AA);
\path [->] (phi*QA) edge node {} (phi*Q*A);
\path [->] (phi*QA) edge [out=270,in=180] node {} (phi*AA);
\path [->] (phi*Q*A) edge [out=270,in=0] node {} (phi*AA);

\path [->,right] (phi*AA) edge node[pos=0.35] {$\beta\phi^*_{AA}$} (phi**AA);

\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\node [slantedbox = $\xi$, fit = (phiQQ)(phiQA)(phiQ*A)(phiAA), minimum height = 3.4cm] at (3,-1) (xi) {};
\node [slantedbox = $\xi_*$, fit = (phi*QA)(phi*Q*A)(phi*AA), minimum height = 3.4cm] at (4,-5.75) (xi*) {};
\node [slantedbox = $\xi_{**}$, fit = (phi**AA), minimum height = 2.6cm] at (4.5,-10) (xi**) {};
\end{pgfonlayer}
```

After manuscriptcentral gets its hands on it and gives me the `pdf` to proof, here is what the corresponding page looks like:

[image]

It should be:

[image]

Any ideas what the problem is and a (low effort) method to fix it?

Comment: My guess is that they have an old version of `tikz`.  Do you have access to a log file from the compilation?  Or use `\pgftypesetversion` to get version information printed in your pdf.

Comment: Does it work if you remove the layered arguments? I think manuscript central fiddles with the background layer to put watermarks. Try putting an empty `backbackground` layer to the layer list. Maybe it would remove the clash.